# Inverse of a 6x6 matrix with (wx)Maxima or XCAS

Tags: matrix, symbolic-math, maxima, wxmaxima

I have to show the inversion of the "**S-matrix**":

[image: S-Matrix]

To obtain the "**C-Matrix**" in the form:
[image: C-Matrix]

which are the relevant instructions/commands for either (wx)Maxima or XCAS?

TIA & BR

Comment: Try `detout: true; invert_by_adjoint(S);` which factors out 1/(determinant of S). Note that the neat forms of expressions which are presented in books often require some insight as to how they can be derived -- automated systems like Maxima often return something which is equivalent to the neat form, but messy. Sometimes `ratsimp`, `factor`, `expand`, or other expression-rearranging functions can help.